# Salvar dicionário Json em txt

Tags: json, python-3.x, arquivo, txt

Como eu posso salvar um. dicionário json de um requests em txt.
tentei fazer desse modo mais não deu certo.

```
import requests
import json

url = requests. get("https://search.ams.usda.gov/farmersmarkets/v1/data.svc/zipSearch?zip=46201")
response = json.loads(url.text)

arquivo = open("dados.txt", "w")
arquivo.write(response)
arquivo.close()
```

Ele cria o arquivo "dados.txt" mais não grava os dados do dicionário json.

Comment: Não seria só salvar o conteúdo da resposta no arquivo? Se o retorno já é no formato JSON, bastaria salvá-lo no arquivo desejado, não tem porque converter para objeto e depois salvá-lo.

Answer (score 1):

troque a linha:

```
arquivo.write(response)
```

por

```
json.dump(response.json(), arquivo)
```

são duas coisas que estavam faltando aí: o método `.json()` do response (que é criado pelo requests) é etraido e transofmrado num objeto de Python  - composto por dicionários ou listas aninhados, strings, números e "None"s - que são os objetos que o JSON consegue des-serializar sozinho.

E na sequência já passamos esse mesmo objeto para a função `dump` do módulo json - que serializa de volta esse objeto simples para uma string, e grava essa string num arquivo.

Dê uma olhada na documentação do [json.dump](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump) - há parâmetros opcionais que permitem que a formatação final no arquivo fique mais prática para ser vista/editada manualmente - ou mais compacta, se a ideia é que o arquivo seja lido e escrito sempre por outros programas.